# Gem vs rails en ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby

Disculpen soy un poco novato en ruby on rails pero mientras ejecuto el servidor de ruby on rails no me funciona el comando rails.
uso el comando
'' gem'' para el servidor 
Nota estoy en windows

mi duda es ¿no es problema para un proyecto real?

*disculpen mi  ignorancia

Comment: `gem` es el gestor de paquetes de Ruby, el cuál te permite instalar y configurar nuevos paquetes. `rails` es el paquete de Ruby on Rails, por lo que son cosas diferentes. ¿Podrías mostrar los mensajes completos cuando ejecutas ambos comandos?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que usas gem para el servidor? ¿Que error te muestra? Agregarlo a la pregunta

Answer (score 3):

Personalmente te recomiendo el uso de [Docker](https://www.docker.com/community-edition) para tu instalación de Rails. Puede intimidar un poco el uso de contenedores y máquinas virtuales al principio pero hay numerosas guías al respecto en internet ([tutorial en web oficial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/), [otro más](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application)).

Con su creciente popularidad, es más y más común que otras personas y/u otros entornos dispongan de un Docker, por tanto, te contaré la ventaja principal de esto: **SIEMPRE** (99% de casos) va a funcionar tu aplicación en cualquier máquina que use Docker.

Answer (score 2):

Trabajar con *Rails* en ambiente *Windows* te traerá varios problemas y a medida que te vayas internando en el *Framework* será peor. Ideal que puedas trabajar bajo plataforma *Linux* o *MacOS*.

Answer (score 1):

hay varios problemas con la instalación de ruby on rails sobre windows.

uno de ellos son las variables de entorno.

te recomiendo que comiences con una instalación "fresca"

utilizando [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)
descargando el paquete completo de instalación para windows

Comment: asi y todo , te recomiendo comenzar sin los problemas tipicos de configuracion de windows , pasa a ubuntu como dice @ArtEze

Answer (score 0):

El comando gem se utiliza para consultar o instalar nuevas gemas, mientras que el comando rails se puede utilizar entre otras cosas para iniciar el servidor (rails server) o accesar a la consola (rails console). Así estés en Windows debería funcionar. De cualquier modo es bastante recomendable que lo trabajes en Linux o Mac. En mi caso lo he hecho en Linux tanto en máquina física como en virtuales con VirtualBox, en ambos casos con Debian 9, aunque podría ser cualquier otro.

Espero haber aportado algo relacionado con la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El lenguaje Ruby utiliza gems que realmente son librerías (así se llaman en otros lenguajes)

Rails es una gem, una librería de Ruby (Ruby on Rails)

Cuando vas a agregar librerías y configuraciones lo mejor es tener apagado el servidor, así que no me queda claro porque quieres ejecutarlo mientras corres comandos de rails.

Con respecto a Windows, a pesar de las críticas, es un buen lugar para comenzar y aprender. Sin embargo a medida que uno sale del nivel principiante debe apuntar a otro S.O.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/344223)

Answer (score 0):

lo correcto es agregar las gemas en el archivo Gemfile y luego corres el bundle inatall y especifica la versión de la gema ya salen nuevas y si no especificas la versión descarga la mas reciente y puede que ya no sea compatible con tu versión de rails

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo es que tienes problemas al ejecutar el comando rails durante la ejecución del servidor de Ruby on Rails.

Para evitarte dolores de cabeza lo mejor seria utilizar Docker para instalar rails, esto te va a evitar muchos problemas de compatibilidad con sistemas operativos y es más facil configurar el entorno de desarrollo, Docker trabaja con contenedores que ya incluyen las dependencias que necesita la apñicacion de Rails.

Aquí puedes encontrar como usar Docker para trabajar con Rails: https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/